# Syntax error in db.collection.save()

Tags: mongodb

I am trying MongoDB for first time but I am stuck on the following syntax error: `unexpected token illegal.` I checked it and it looks OK. I found similar a problem on StackOverflow but that is for a different error. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my script:

```
db.student.save({"_id":ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7),"name":"replaced","age":55})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here : `ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7)`

ObjectId accepts a string of 24 hex digits.

```
ObjectId("<24 hex digits here>")
```

E.g. `ObjectId("0123456789abcdef01234567")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a backend source code such as groovy (with Grails GORM), you can try the following script which is very clean and readable:

```
def studentFromDB = db.student.findById("5983548781331adf45ec7")
studentFromDB.name = "replaced"
studentFromDB.age = 55
studentFromDB.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

If you use it directly onto the mongo you should use the [MongoDB update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), for example:

```
db.student.update(
   {"_id":ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7) },
   {
      name: "replaced",
      age: 55
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...the error is i missed quotes inside 'ObjectId'
the corrected script is `db.student.save({"_id":ObjectId("57fcf46763ecce707f071884"),"name":"rep_dsave","age":37}).

Thanks   4J41  and rotemy

`

Comment: Hi MSGK: if 4J41's answer solved the problem for you, then the right thing to do is to upvote and accept 4J41's answer - not to post it as a separate answer yourself.